# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined on react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm have the title error on my application but i don't know how to solve this problem.
This is my application running:

[First-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmfUj.png.)

When i click on each of these maps, a shadow is rendered on them and they are passed to a list on redux state, also a counter of how many maps you have completed it's showed.

[Second-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlVTY.png)

When you click the button awakened, the maps are re-rendered and new tier of maps are shown, and you can also click them to complete each map. Works just like the normal map logic.

[First step to error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT8X0.png)

This third image it's just like the first, the difference is that i took out one map of the list, and here is where the error occurs, at this point nothing wrong happens, but the moment i click the "awakened" button the application stops and it give me that error.
I know where the error it's happening, but i didn't figure out how to solve it.

This is the component i'm working on:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";

import { Container } from "./styles";

import "./mapsScss";

import { mapCompleted, mapUncompleted, awakenedMapCompleted, awakenedMapUncompleted } from "./mapActions";

const base_map = require("./map_base_icon.png");

const Map = props => {
    const { maps, awakenedMaps } = props;

    const toggleCompletedMap = id => {
        if (maps.includes(props.id)) {
            props.mapUncompleted(id);
        } else {
            props.mapCompleted(id);
        }
    };

    const toggleAwakenedCompletedMap = id => {
        if (awakenedMaps.includes(props.id)) {
            props.awakenedMapUncompleted(id);
        } else {
            props.awakenedMapCompleted(id);
        }
    };

    const onClickToggle = () => {
        if (props.normalActive) {
            toggleCompletedMap(props.id);
        }
        if (props.awakenedActive) {
            toggleAwakenedCompletedMap(props.id);
        }
    };

    const baseMapRender = () => {
        if (props.color_tag === "Unique") {
            return;
        } else {
            return <img src={base_map} alt="Base Map" />;
        }
    };

    return (
        <Container id={props.id}>
            <div className="map_name">{props.map_name}</div>
            <div>
                {baseMapRender()}
                <img src={props.map_color} alt={`${props.map_name} ${props.color_tag} Map`} />
                <div
                    className={`toggle-completed  
                    ${props.normalActive ? (maps.includes(props.id) ? "completed-map" : "") : ""}
                    ${props.awakenedActive ? (awakenedMaps.includes(props.id) ? "completed-awakened-map" : "") : ""}
                    `}
                    onClick={onClickToggle}
                ></div>
            </div>
            <div className="map_tier">Tier {props.map_tier}</div>
        </Container>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    maps: state.map.maps,
    awakenedMaps: state.map.awakenedMaps,
    normalActive: state.atlas.normalActive,
    awakenedActive: state.atlas.awakenedActive,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
    bindActionCreators(
        {
            mapCompleted,
            mapUncompleted,
            awakenedMapCompleted,
            awakenedMapUncompleted,
        },
        dispatch,
    );

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Map);
```

this is the action creatos file:

```
export const mapCompleted = id => ({
    type: "MAP_COMPLETED",
    payload: id,
});

export const mapUncompleted = id => ({
    type: "MAP_UNCOMPLETED",
    payload: id,
});

export const awakenedMapCompleted = id => ({
    type: "AWAKENED_MAP_COMPLETED",
    payload: id,
});

export const awakenedMapUncompleted = id => ({
    type: "AWAKENED_MAP_UNCOMPLETED",
    payload: id,
});
```

and this is the reducers file:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    maps: [],
    mapCounter: 0,
    awakenedMaps: [],
    awakenedMapCounter: 0,
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "MAP_COMPLETED":
            return { ...state, maps: [...state.maps, action.payload], mapCounter: state.mapCounter + 1 };
        case "MAP_UNCOMPLETED":
            return { maps: state.maps.filter(item => item !== action.payload), mapCounter: state.mapCounter - 1 };
        case "AWAKENED_MAP_COMPLETED":
            return {
                ...state,
                awakenedMaps: [...state.awakenedMaps, action.payload],
                awakenedMapCounter: state.awakenedMapCounter + 1,
            };
        case "AWAKENED_MAP_UNCOMPLETED":
            return {
                awakenedMaps: state.awakenedMaps.filter(item => item !== action.payload),
                awakenedMapCounter: state.awakenedMapCounter - 1,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Comment: Sorry, missed the `connect` call.

Comment: Sorry for that, i'm kinda new to stack, i'll do what you asked, thank you for the fast answer :)

Comment: :-) Even though the use of `Map` **is** in the question (I just missed it at first), it is worth doing that [mcve] demonstrating the problem; [here's that link to how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: reading it, i'll just edit it in a minute!

Comment: T.J. i was ready to write the reproduced error, but the friend below just answered my question, ty anyway man! best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems that need fix as I can see
Here

```
    case "AWAKENED_MAP_UNCOMPLETED":
        return {
            awakenedMaps: state.awakenedMaps.filter(item => item !== action.payload),
            awakenedMapCounter: state.awakenedMapCounter - 1,
        };
```

and here

```
    case "MAP_UNCOMPLETED":
        return { maps: state.maps.filter(item => item !== action.payload), mapCounter: state.mapCounter - 1 };
```

you don't return the previous state, so the other properties are lost and will become undefined. This will reflect at next update of your component where you check with `includes` function

Try these

```
    case "AWAKENED_MAP_UNCOMPLETED":
        return {...state,
            awakenedMaps: state.awakenedMaps.filter(item => item !== action.payload),
            awakenedMapCounter: state.awakenedMapCounter - 1,
        };
```

and

```
    case "MAP_UNCOMPLETED":
        return { ...state, maps: state.maps.filter(item => item !== action.payload), mapCounter: state.mapCounter - 1 };
```

Comment: thanks a lot man, this solved my problem, i completely forgot about return the previous state! best regards